# How to get ec2 metadata to reflect the new hostname?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have changed the hostname on my ec2 instance following the steps here:
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/set-hostname.html

However, the metadata service still returns the old hostname even after i rebooted my instance. How can I make the metadata return the new hostname?

Comment: what is the old hostname? is this the publicly reachable dns name?

Comment: No, it's a private DNS name. The old hostname used us-west-2.compute.internal domain. I changed it to xyz.net

Answer (score 4):

I'm afraid it can't be done or at least there is no documentation on how to do that. I think instance metadata is calculated upon instance configuration and launch.

I would suggest retrieving your hostname through the OS itself, it is HOSTNAME environment variable or the output of hostname command e.g.:

PHP:

```
echo gethostname();
```

Bash script:

```
echo `hostname`;
echo $HOSTNAME;
```